# How to update my visual studio ultimate 2013 to update 4 in my existing visual studio copy

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-identity

I have my visual studio 2013 ultimate installed on my local machine.Now , to use the latest AspNet Identity 2.0, i am recommended to use 2013 update 2 or higher.
So, I go to microsoft website and starts downloading.First, it downloaded the small 1.8mb .exe file on my machine.
when i run this .exe file, it starts downloading **8GB** visual studio from msdn website.

**I just want to know if i have with myself, visual studio 2013 ultimate so to upgrade it , i have to download whole 8 gb file or is there any more update button in visual studio from where i can download only upgrade not the whole visual studio again from the starting.**

Comment: this is the last update http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48129

Comment: @AvsenevSlava but how to download only the update not the full visual studio 2013 ???

Comment: @AvsenevSlava After downloading and running The screen prompt shows---- This installation will update all the visual studio 2013 products nad languages which are currently installed..When complete , this update will use upto 8,193 mb of disk space.......Now , what should i do now

Comment: @AvsenevSlava i don't want to start installation and stop it in the middle. if i do this, may be my running visual studio become corrupt.??? thats why i am fearing.... have u tried it ???

Comment: then dont stop it during installation